# Reuse an object in another assembly..need help knowing where to look / what to learn for an answer

Tags: c#, .net

Probably get down voted but I need my problem identified so I know what / where to look for an answer.

I have "settings" object1 defined in assembly A. object is properties but not same as B, C, D

I have "settings" object2 defined in assembly B. object is properties but not same as A, C, D

I have "settings" object3 defined in assembly C. object is properties but not same as A, B, D

I have "settings" object4 defined in assembly D. object is properties but not same as A, B, C

etc....

These "settings" objects will all have one common property. Property Q.

Object L will ALWAYS be installed but A-D will be in different combinations. So I am OK with A-D having a reference to L but I do not want L to reference A-D.

I have a method in assembly L that is consumed by A, B, C, D, etc. This method is going to look for property Q in the settings object.

I don't want to do some ugly hack testing / trying / poking until I find which assembly setting object is being passed. Further assembly E may be added and I'd like to NOT have to rebuild assembly L to add another "setting" object to the hack to look for..

It seems I want to use Generics and reflection possibly but just not sure if that is correct?

> So to zoom in a bit closer her is an example of the settings objects:

```
//ASSEMBLY A
namespace User.Purchase.Product.A
{
    class SettingsA
   {
       public string Name{get;set;}
       public string Rank{get;set;}
       public string Serial{get;set;}
       public string Active{get;set;}
   }

   class DoWorkA
   {
      var PPP = new Object L; //psuedo code
      PPP.GetSettings(typeof(SettingsA));
   }

}


//ASSEMBLY B
namespace User.Purchase.Product.B
{
    class SettingsB
   {
       public string Branch{get;set;}
       public string MOS{get;set;}
       public string Promotion{get;set;}
       public string Active{get;set;}
   }

    class DoWorkB
   {
      var PPP = new Object L; //psuedo code
      PPP.GetSettings(typeof(SettingsB));
   }
}

//ASSEMBLY SettingsC
namespace User.Purchase.Product.C
{
    class C
   {
       public string Vehicle{get;set;}
       public string Engine{get;set;}
       public string FuelType{get;set;}
       public string Active{get;set;}
   }

   class DoWorkC
   {
      var PPP = new Object L; //psuedo code
      PPP.GetSettings(typeof(SettingsC));
   }
}
```

> Common Assembly L

```
//ASSEMBLY L
namespace User.Common.Library
{
    class L
   {
      public bool GetSettings(Type type) //???? What / how to pass my generic object
      {
          ....somehow using reflection dynamically build my object definition for use
          by settings service below.

          var TTT = SomeManipulation(type); //obvious psuedo code here

          var xyz = settingService.LoadConfigObject<TTT>();

          if(xyz.Q)
          {...}

         //the settingService is already in existence and I would prefer to use it
         //instead of breaking DRY and creating an implementation just for this purpose.
      }
   }
}
```

> Again my apologies for such a cloudy question.

I am just looking for some direction into what I need to learn to make sense of this situation....or perhaps I need to modify my architecture ecause I have painted myself into a corner etc.

Thank You for you patience and assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make another assembly and add an interface to that assembly that specifies the common parts between all those settings objects.

ie. like this:

```
public interface ICommonSettings
{
    string Q { get; set; }
}
```

Then reference this new assembly from projects A-D and L and implement this interface on those 4 settings objects. The code in L that will consume the settings objects from A-D can look for that interface and determine both that the setting object implements the common parts but also use the "right way" to access those properties.

Reference-wise you would have this, where "A --> B" means A refers to B:

[image: illustration]

You can also place the interface into the L assembly, as long as L doesn't require a reference to A-D, this way you would reduce the number of assemblies required. However, personally I feel the interface-only assembly is a better approach since you've extracted the bits that you say "A 3rd part dll can rely on these bits".

Comment: Ohhh that's a great idea. So I would end up having two assemblies that are mandatory installs. Assembly L & Assembly Iface.  So is there a name or concept for this situation that I need to educate myself on?

Comment: @user1278561 The term for this approach is a "Plugin system". There is [example code projects](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-a-simple-plugin-b6174b62) on the MSDN. In that link the `PluginContracts` assembly represents "Assembly Iface" from your comment and `FirstPlugin` and `SecondPlugin` represent your lettered assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

In the same assembly that contains class L, create a settings interface that provides the Q property (IQProvider in my example)

```
public interface IQProvider
{
    string Q { get; set; }
}

class SettingsA : IQProvider
{
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public string Rank{get;set;}
   public string Serial{get;set;}
   public string Active{get;set;}
   public string Q { get; set; }
}
```

Then your GetSettings method can accept that as a parameter, no more reflection!

```
class L
{
  public bool GetSettings(IQProvider qProvider)
  {
      return qProvider.Q.Equals("BLAH");
  }
}
```